# Replace resource user_id with something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'd like to use something like `domain.com/users/foo` instead of the routes looking like `/users/user_id/`

Fair enough you could do `get "/users/:name/.....` but I am using nested resource:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }

  resources :users do
    resource :profile
    resources :supports do
      post :interest
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to change the resource `users/user_id` to `users/firstname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you can use [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) or you can define `to_param` method in your user model.

```
def to_param
  "#{name}"
end
```

Comment: Although that worked, is there a way to change in the routes.rb?

Comment: @Sylar if you use `to_param` make sure each name is unique. The `friendly_id` gem is a nice alternative (it generates unique slugs). Upvoted.

Comment: I'm using twitter auth so their username would be unique.

Comment: @Sylar then you're good to go. Also, it's much better to have this handled directly in the model than in the routes definition. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because Im replacing `user_id` with `twitter_username` and wand to use `User.find( params[:twitter_username] )`

Comment: Then my resource would not work. I need something like `users/@name/profile/etc`